# uiimageview transparent to rearmost layer

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, core-graphics, mask

I have a question concerning an uiimageview. I have multiple ImageViews overlapping each other and one background image(view). The ImageViews are moving in a carousel.

I want all uiimagesviews which are rotating in a carousel (and overlapping each other) to be only transparent to the background image. Otherwise I see the border of the next uiimageview which is overlapping.

How to achieve this?

EDIT: Added Screenshot to show the problem at overlapping items:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your carousel ?

Comment: I added the screenshot, imagine the colored background is an image and I don't want these intersections. I just want to cut this overlapping pieces out of the box which is lying below a bigger box.